# Typedef inside a class

Tags: c++, typedef

How do I typedef inside a function?
let's consider class B has an int x datamember. When I try to compile the following I get:  expected initializer before ‘.’ token

In this example everything is simple, but for my code, I will be doing something like test.x.y.z.f. So I have multiple objects within objects until I get to the datamember I need, so typedef would help.

```
class A
{
  B test;

  A(B test1)
  { 
    test = test1;
  }

  function f()
  {
    typedef test.x x; //how come this doesn't compile?

  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can typedef objects or data-members only types

Comment: What are you trying to do with the typedef? It looks like you're trying to access a member variable, not declare a type. I think you need to read up on what typedef does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typedef introduces a name for a *type*.
`test.x` is a variable, not a type.
It is *an* `int`, but it's not the type `int` itself.

If you want to introduce a new name for a variable, use *references*.

```
int& x = test.x;  // "x" is now a different name for test.x
int& y = test.x.y.z.f; // "y" is now a different name for test.x.y.z.f.
```

Answer (score 4):

`x` is a *variable* not a *type*. In C++11 you could use `decltype` to determine the type of `x`:

```
void f()
{
    decltype(test.x) x;
}
```

Or, you could just declare a local reference to the member you wish to work with:

```
void f()
{
    auto& x_ref(test.x); // Or explictly state the type.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simulate `typedef` with a variable use a reference. `type_of_x& x = test.x;`

Comment: What is the type of `B::x`?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* what you are asking for is a way to "shorthand" the content of a long sequence of names. The way I've done this in the past (where relevant) is to use a reference:

```
struct Blah
{
  int x, y, z;
};

class X
{
   Blah *arr[10];

   X()
   {
      for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
         arr[i] = new Blah;
      }
   }
}

class Y
{
   X var;
};


Y y;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     y.var.arr[i]->x *= 4; 
     y.var.arr[i]->y *= 3; 
     y.var.arr[i]->z *= 5; 
}
```

can be written as:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     Blah &b = y.var.arr[i];

     b.x *= 4; 
     b.y *= 3; 
     b.z *= 5; 
}
```

Now, that's a bit easier to read, isn't it?